# ejabberd - http://localhost:5280 redirects to www.localhost.com:5280

Tags: localhost, xmpp, ejabberd

I am learning xmpp programming and I installed ejabberd on my ubuntu 15.10 using `sudo apt-get install ejabberd` and then I configured the installation by adding an admin user `ejabberdctl register admin localhost password`. But whenever I try to go to `localhost:5280`  from my firefox browser, it redirects me to `www.localhost.com:5280` which says `server not found`. On the other hand, chrome browser says `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` - Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

I tried `localhost:5269` and it returns:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:server' xmlns:db='jabber:server:dialback' id='923657800'>
<stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>
</xml-not-well-formed></stream:error></stream:stream>
```

Is there anything wrong with my `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml`? Should I post it too?

Please help. Thank you.

> EDIT: added ejabberd.yml

```
###
###               ejabberd configuration file
###
###

### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained in more detail
### in the ejabberd Installation and Operation Guide.
### Please consult the Guide in case of doubts, it is included with
### your copy of ejabberd, and is also available online at
### http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/

### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
### However, ejabberd treats different literals as different types:
###
### - unquoted or single-quoted strings. They are called "atoms".
###   Example: dog, 'Jupiter', '3.14159', YELLOW
###
### - numeric literals. Example: 3, -45.0, .0
###
### - quoted or folded strings.
###   Examples of quoted string: "Lizzard", "orange".
###   Example of folded string:
###   > Art thou not Romeo,
###     and a Montague?

###   =======
###   LOGGING

##
## loglevel: Verbosity of log files generated by ejabberd.
## 0: No ejabberd log at all (not recommended)
## 1: Critical
## 2: Error
## 3: Warning
## 4: Info
## 5: Debug
##
loglevel: 4

##
## rotation: Disable ejabberd's internal log rotation, as the Debian package
## uses logrotate(8).
log_rotate_size: 0
log_rotate_date: ""

##
## overload protection: If you want to limit the number of messages per second
## allowed from error_logger, which is a good idea if you want to avoid a flood
## of messages when system is overloaded, you can set a limit.
## 100 is ejabberd's default.
log_rate_limit: 100

##
## watchdog_admins: Only useful for developers: if an ejabberd process
## consumes a lot of memory, send live notifications to these XMPP
## accounts.
##
## watchdog_admins:
##   - "bob@example.com"


###   ================
###   SERVED HOSTNAMES

##
## hosts: Domains served by ejabberd.
## You can define one or several, for example:
## hosts: 
##   - "example.net"
##   - "example.com"
##   - "example.org"
##
hosts:
  - "localhost"

##
## route_subdomains: Delegate subdomains to other XMPP servers.
## For example, if this ejabberd serves example.org and you want
## to allow communication with an XMPP server called im.example.org.
##
## route_subdomains: s2s

###   ===============
###   LISTENING PORTS

##
## listen: The ports ejabberd will listen on, which service each is handled
## by and what options to start it with.
##
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    ##
    ## If TLS is compiled in and you installed a SSL
    ## certificate, specify the full path to the
    ## file and uncomment these lines:
    ##
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
    starttls: true
    ##
    ## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
    ## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
    ##
    ## starttls_required: true
    ##
    ## Custom OpenSSL options
    ##
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    ##   - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  - 
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
  ##
  ## ejabberd_service: Interact with external components (transports, ...)
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 8888
  ##   module: ejabberd_service
  ##   access: all
  ##   shaper_rule: fast
  ##   ip: "127.0.0.1"
  ##   hosts:
  ##     "icq.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"
  ##     "sms.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"

  ##
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 3478
  ##   transport: udp
  ##   module: ejabberd_stun

  ##
  ## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
  - 
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    ## request_handlers:
    ##   "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_poll: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: true
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

##
## s2s_use_starttls: Enable STARTTLS + Dialback for S2S connections.
## Allowed values are: false optional required required_trusted
## You must specify a certificate file.
##
s2s_use_starttls: optional

##
## s2s_certfile: Specify a certificate file.
##
s2s_certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

## Custom OpenSSL options
##
s2s_protocol_options:
  - "no_sslv3"
##   - "no_tlsv1"

##
## domain_certfile: Specify a different certificate for each served hostname.
##
## host_config:
##   "example.org":
##     domain_certfile: "/path/to/example_org.pem"
##   "example.com":
##     domain_certfile: "/path/to/example_com.pem"

##
## S2S whitelist or blacklist
##
## Default s2s policy for undefined hosts.
##
## s2s_access: s2s

##
## Outgoing S2S options
##
## Preferred address families (which to try first) and connect timeout
## in milliseconds.
##
## outgoing_s2s_families:
##   - ipv4
##   - ipv6
## outgoing_s2s_timeout: 10000

###   ==============
###   AUTHENTICATION

##
## auth_method: Method used to authenticate the users.
## The default method is the internal.
## If you want to use a different method,
## comment this line and enable the correct ones.
##
auth_method: internal

##
## Store the plain passwords or hashed for SCRAM:
## auth_password_format: plain
## auth_password_format: scram
##
## Define the FQDN if ejabberd doesn't detect it:
## fqdn: "server3.example.com"

##
## Authentication using external script
## Make sure the script is executable by ejabberd.
##
## auth_method: external
## extauth_program: "/path/to/authentication/script"

##
## Authentication using ODBC
## Remember to setup a database in the next section.
##
## auth_method: odbc

##
## Authentication using PAM
##
## auth_method: pam
## pam_service: "pamservicename"

##
## Authentication using LDAP
##
## auth_method: ldap
##
## List of LDAP servers:
## ldap_servers:
##   - "localhost"
##
## Encryption of connection to LDAP servers:
## ldap_encrypt: none
## ldap_encrypt: tls
##
## Port to connect to on LDAP servers:
## ldap_port: 389
## ldap_port: 636
##
## LDAP manager:
## ldap_rootdn: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## Password of LDAP manager:
## ldap_password: "******"
##
## Search base of LDAP directory:
## ldap_base: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## LDAP attribute that holds user ID:
## ldap_uids:
##   - "mail": "%u@mail.example.org"
##
## LDAP filter:
## ldap_filter: "(objectClass=shadowAccount)"

##
## Anonymous login support:
##   auth_method: anonymous
##   anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon | login_anon | both
##   allow_multiple_connections: true | false
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method: anonymous
##     allow_multiple_connections: false
##     anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon
##
## To use both anonymous and internal authentication:
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method:
##       - internal
##       - anonymous

###   ==============
###   DATABASE SETUP

## ejabberd by default uses the internal Mnesia database,
## so you do not necessarily need this section.
## This section provides configuration examples in case
## you want to use other database backends.
## Please consult the ejabberd Guide for details on database creation.

##
## MySQL server:
##
## odbc_type: mysql
## odbc_server: "server"
## odbc_database: "database"
## odbc_username: "username"
## odbc_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
## odbc_port: 1234

##
## PostgreSQL server:
##
## odbc_type: pgsql
## odbc_server: "server"
## odbc_database: "database"
## odbc_username: "username"
## odbc_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
## odbc_port: 1234
##
## If you use PostgreSQL, have a large database, and need a
## faster but inexact replacement for "select count(*) from users"
##
## pgsql_users_number_estimate: true

##
## ODBC compatible or MSSQL server:
##
## odbc_type: odbc
## odbc_server: "DSN=ejabberd;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"

##
## Number of connections to open to the database for each virtual host
##
## odbc_pool_size: 10

##
## Interval to make a dummy SQL request to keep the connections to the
## database alive. Specify in seconds: for example 28800 means 8 hours
##
## odbc_keepalive_interval: undefined

###   ===============
###   TRAFFIC SHAPERS

shaper:
  ##
  ## The "normal" shaper limits traffic speed to 1000 B/s
  ##
  normal: 1000

  ##
  ## The "fast" shaper limits traffic speed to 50000 B/s
  ##
  fast: 50000

##
## This option specifies the maximum number of elements in the queue
## of the FSM. Refer to the documentation for details.
##
max_fsm_queue: 1000

###.   ====================
###'   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
     user:
         - "": "localhost"

  ##
  ## Blocked users
  ##
  ## blocked:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "baduser": "example.org"
  ##     - "test"

  ## Local users: don't modify this.
  ##
  local: 
    user_regexp: ""

  ##
  ## More examples of ACLs
  ##
  ## jabberorg:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "jabber.org"
  ## aleksey:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "aleksey": "jabber.ru"
  ## test:
  ##   user_regexp: "^test"
  ##   user_glob: "test*"

  ##
  ## Loopback network
  ##
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"

  ##
  ## Bad XMPP servers
  ##
  ## bad_servers:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "xmpp.zombie.org"
  ##     - "xmpp.spam.com"

##
## Define specific ACLs in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     acl:
##       admin:
##         user:
##           - "bob-local": "localhost"

###   ============
###   ACCESS RULES
access:
  ## Maximum number of simultaneous sessions allowed for a single user:
  max_user_sessions: 
    all: 10
  ## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
  max_user_offline_messages: 
    admin: 5000
    all: 100
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local: 
    local: allow
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s: 
    blocked: deny
    all: allow
  ## For C2S connections, all users except admins use the "normal" shaper
  c2s_shaper: 
    admin: none
    all: normal
  ## All S2S connections use the "fast" shaper
  s2s_shaper: 
    all: fast
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure: 
    admin: allow
  ## Admins of this server are also admins of the MUC service:
  muc_admin: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create: 
    local: allow
  ## All users are allowed to use the MUC service:
  muc: 
    all: allow
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode: 
    local: allow
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register: 
    all: allow
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## s2s: 
  ##   bad_servers: deny
  ##   all: allow

## By default the frequency of account registrations from the same IP
## is limited to 1 account every 10 minutes. To disable, specify: infinity
## registration_timeout: 600

##
## Define specific Access Rules in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     access:
##       c2s:
##         admin: allow
##         all: deny
##       register:
##         all: deny

###   ================
###   DEFAULT LANGUAGE

##
## language: Default language used for server messages.
##
language: "en"

##
## Set a different default language in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     language: "ru"

###   =======
###   CAPTCHA

##
## Full path to a script that generates the image.
##
## captcha_cmd: "/lib/ejabberd/priv/bin/captcha.sh"

##
## Host for the URL and port where ejabberd listens for CAPTCHA requests.
##
## captcha_host: "example.org:5280"

##
## Limit CAPTCHA calls per minute for JID/IP to avoid DoS.
##
## captcha_limit: 5

###   =======
###   MODULES

##
## Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
##
modules: 
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state:
    drop_chat_states: true
    queue_presence: false
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  ## mod_echo: {}
  mod_irc: {}
  mod_http_bind: {}
  ## mod_http_fileserver:
  ##   docroot: "/var/www"
  ##   accesslog: "/var/log/ejabberd/access.log"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc: 
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_admin: muc_admin
  ## mod_muc_log: {}
  mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  ## mod_proxy65: {}
  mod_pubsub: 
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ## reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    ## XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
    ## ignore_pep_from_offline: false
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins: 
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_register: 
    ##
    ## Protect In-Band account registrations with CAPTCHA.
    ##
    ## captcha_protected: true

    ##
    ## Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
    ##
    ## password_strength: 32

    ##
    ## After successful registration, the user receives
    ## a message with this subject and body.
    ##
    welcome_message: 
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.

    ##
    ## When a user registers, send a notification to
    ## these XMPP accounts.
    ##
    ## registration_watchers:
    ##   - "admin1@example.org"

    ##
    ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ip_access: trusted_network

    ##
    ## Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
    ##
    ## access_from: deny

    access: register
  mod_roster: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stats: {}
  mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_version: {}

##
## Enable modules with custom options in a specific virtual host
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     modules:
##       mod_echo:
##         host: "mirror.localhost"

##
## Enable modules management via ejabberdctl for installation and
## uninstallation of public/private contributed modules
## (enabled by default)
##

allow_contrib_modules: true

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Comment: Have you tried in some other browser like chrome? It would be better if you update you ejabberd.yml in your question

Comment: @Yashwanth, I have added the ejabberd.yml file. Please hellp me out with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be that the ejabberd server is not running on your local machine or there is a typo in the URL you type in your browser.

To check if the server is running fine, you can use a command-line tool like curl and check the response:

```
curl http://localhost:5280/
```

Looking at your config file, one issue is that you have enable tls, certfile on port 5280 listener and you are trying to connect using http and not HTTPS. It cannot work. Please, note that your use of the ip option is also probably not needed and may interfer.

Comment: on doing that, it gives me the following output: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: It is giving me the same output, `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure you are connected to ejabberd server. Put the server in debug mode (loglevel 5) and check if you are seeing traffic coming from your browser or curl.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Can you please guide me through the steps please? I am new to this.

Comment: change ejabber.yml file, look for loglevel and set it to 5. then check in ejabberd.log file if you see mention about receiving connection in log. I suspect you are not connecting to ejabberd at all.

Comment: `2015-11-05 16:27:31.746 [info] <0.455.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:309 (#Port<0.7735>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:58398 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2015-11-05 16:27:31.790 [info] <0.499.0>@ejabberd_http:init:149 started: {p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.7735>,#Port<0.7738>}}`
This is what my ejabberd.log is showing while I try to  hit `localhost:5280`

Comment: `2015-11-05 16:29:33.522 [info] <0.455.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:309 (#Port<0.7739>) Accepted connection ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:58564 -> ::FFFF:127.0.0.1:5280
2015-11-05 16:29:33.522 [info] <0.502.0>@ejabberd_http:init:149 started: {p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.7739>,#Port<0.7740>}}` - This is my log when I hit `localhost:5280/admin`

Comment: You seem to have enable tls and trying to connect with non tls connection.

Comment: Remove tls, ip and certfile on 5280 listener or try connecting using https.

Comment: I tried connecting `https://localhost:5280/admin` and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

1-stop ejabberd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ejabberd stop
```

2-Edit Hostname in ejabberd.cfg

```
sudo nano /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg
```

---

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Options which are set by Debconf and managed by ucf

%% Admin user
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "localhost.com"}}.

%% Hostname
{hosts, ["localhost.com"]}.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

3-start ejabberd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ejabberd start
```

Answer (score 1):

ejabberd admin url should be:  http://localhost:5280/admin